# how to delete/remove the class added to a tag once clicking a new element.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have a series of images, once clicking an image am adding a class to it.

if i click another image class should be removed from previous image and added to the new clicked image.

code

HTML Code

```
<ul id='carousel_ul'>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/thumbnails/image1.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/thumbnails/image2.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/thumbnails/image3.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery Code

```
$("#carousel_ul li a img").click(function(){

        $(this).addClass("someclass");
});
```

So when i click a new image, the class should be removed from old one and added to newly clicked image.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#carousel_ul li a img").click(function(){
        $('.someclass').removeClass('someclass');
        $(this).addClass("someclass");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple :

```
$("#carousel_ul li a img").click(function(){
        $(".someclass").removeClass("someclass");
        $(this).addClass("someclass");
});
```

Comment: Wow people are too fast for me

Comment: ha! the dot was missing ;)

Comment: Somebody corrected the correction of my corrected message. Good work boys.

Answer (score 0):

test it like this

```
$("#carousel_ul li a img").click(function(){
    $("#carousel_ul .someclass").removeClass("someclass");
    $(this).addClass("someclass");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#carousel_ul li a img").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass(".someclass");
    $(this).addClass(".someclass");
});
```

Or this way :D